# Internal Server Error: Django, uWsgi, Nginx, Pyenv

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, pyenv

I am trying to serve a Django application using Nginx and uWsgi

I followed

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://serverfault.com/questions/775965/wiring-uwsgi-to-work-with-django-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

for same.

platforms.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
project = platforms
base = /home/ubuntu

chdir = /home/ubuntu/platforms/
home = /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/platforms-hQBv-BwK/
module = platforms.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5
logger = file:/home/ubuntu/platforms/logs/uwsgi.log

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
```

uwsgi.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
vacuum = true
```

When I run the application using below command

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --home /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/platforms-hQBv-BwK --chdir /home/ubuntu/platforms -w platforms.wsgi
```

it works fine.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

works fine

But when i run using ini file

I get

```
internal server error
```

also in the logs i am getting

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 6752|app: -1|req: -1/7] xx.xxx.xxx.xx () {44 vars in 904 bytes} [Wed Mar 11 07:12:50 2020] GET /admin/ => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

I am unable to figure out what could be issue. Please Help.

Comment: you have to activate your environment before running manage.py command

Comment: running using management command is working. It throws error when i run it as a service using sudo service uwsgi start

Comment: no python application found error occurs when env is not activated

Comment: @ankit I'm having the same issue - did you find a working solution with pyenv? I also tried to use the uwsgi from the venv and it failed as well.